# Slopes of curves from complex derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, geometry

Show that the slopes of the level curves$$u(x,y)=\text{constant} \ \ \text{and} \ \ v(x,y)=\text{constant}$$ are respectively given by $$\cot(\arg(f'(z))) \ \ \text{and} \ \ -\tan(\arg(f'(z)))$$ If $f$ is analytic and $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. I'm working my way through Polya's "Complex Variables" and I'm stuck on this one, in the section on conformal mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's prove the result for $u(x,y)$, the proof for $v(x,y)$ being similar.

On one hand, for a level curve $u(x,y)=k$, the slope at a point $(x,y(x))$ is given by $$y^\prime(x)=-\frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y(x))}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y(x))} \tag 1$$

On the other hand, for a complex number $z$, we have $$\cot (\arg (z))=\frac{\Re(z)}{\Im(z)}=\frac{i(z+ \overline z)}{z - \overline z} \tag 2$$

Now as $f$ is supposed to be analytic we have $f^\prime(z)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$. Applying (2) to the complex $f^\prime(z)$ we get $$\cot (\arg (f^\prime(z)))=\frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}}$$ Finally we obtain the desired result using following Cauchy-Riemann equation (as $f$ is analytic) $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$